# Trigger a login by plugging in a USB drive

Tags: linux-mint, login, udev, login-manager

OS: Linux, Mint.

I want to have a system where I can insert a flashdrive into a computer, and using UDEV rules, have the system login a user account. I can do the UDEV part, but what command should I run to login? Google has not helped, nor has poking around the computer.